# Background overlapping player when the player layer is after the background layer

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating a 2D platformer in unity and here is all of my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 0.5f;
    public float gravity;

    private float x;
    private float y;

    private bool isLeft = false;
    private bool isRight = false;
    private bool isUp = false;
    private bool isDown = false;

    public SpriteRenderer sp;
    public Sprite player_Right;
    public Sprite player_Left;

    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(Screen.width + "," + Screen.height);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        x = transform.position.x;
        y = transform.position.y;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("right"))
        {
            isRight = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("left"))
        {
            isLeft = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("up"))
        {
            isUp = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("down"))
        {
            isDown = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp("right"))
        {
            isRight = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp("left"))
        {
            isLeft = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp("up"))
        {
            isUp = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp("down"))
        {
            isDown = false;
        }

        if (isRight)
        {
            x += speed * Time.deltaTime;
            sp.sprite = player_Right;
        }
        if (isLeft)
        {
            x -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
            sp.sprite = player_Left;
        }
        if (isDown)
        {
            y -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (isUp)
        {
            y += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }


        transform.position = new Vector2(x, y);
    }
}
```

Here is my edit layers screen:

[image: edit layers]

The background image is attached to the background layer and the player is attached to the player layer so the player should always be drawn on top of the background right?
Well I thought that and when I press play whenever I go left the player disappears beneath the background. Why does this happen and how can I fix it? If you need to see some part of the editor do not hesitate to ask.

**EDIT:** For some reason the tag automatically switches from unity 2d to unity 3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe lot of us encounter this problem when we try to create 2D game, but the function of `layer` is not for that purpose, here is two solutions for player on top of the background:

1. Depending on your camera position, you can set **player's position closer to camera than background image's position to camera**, e.g camera position is `(0, 0, 10)`, then you set player's position to `(0, 0, 1)` and background image's position to `(0, 0, 0)`
2. Set the player's `Order In Layer` parameter in **Sprite Renderer component** smaller than in background images, because lower numbered Sprites are rendered first, with higher numbered Sprites overlapping those below, e.g `0` for player, `1` for background image